# Javascript onnclick call a function in ejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, ejs

I am looping through an array, in my loop i have this function that sets the array item id to localstorage

```
 <% if (result.length > 0) { %>
      <%result.map((item,index) => { %>
         <%  function check() { 
          localStorage.setItem("product_id", item.id); 
         }%>
         <a onclick='check()' href="#">
          <span>Edit</span>
        </a>

     <% }) %>
 <% }
```

This is where an calling the function, still inside the loop

```
    <a onclick='check()' href="#">
       <span>Edit</span>
    </a>
```

I want onclick of this anchor tag to call that function at the top, but its giving me this error

```
    products:329 Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined
        at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (products:329)
    onclick @ products:329
```

Comment: Your syntax isn't valid or the snippet is incomplete. Anyway, you have defined check inside of the map call.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes its incomplete, i will quickly update it, and yes the function is in a map and its also been called in the map function, is that wrong?

Comment: @AluanHaddad it has be updated

Comment: A JavaScript function defined in the EJS program (which runs on the server) is not accessible in a completely different JavaScript program running in the rendered webpage in the browser.